# Is it possible to make this query working properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm creating a simple game and I want to get the best **lap_time** for each **type** in the db.
However, my query returns the wrong **player_id** (3 in second row) and **total_ranks** (all ranks instead of count by type).

Link to sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c36a/2

**Desired result**

```
+--------+-----+-------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| level  | cp  | type  | player_id  | MIN(lap_time)  | total_ranks |
+--------+-----+-------+------------+----------------+-------------+
|     1  |  1  |    0  |         1  |          10.5  |           4 |
|     1  |  1  |    1  |         2  |         10.45  |           3 |
+--------+-----+-------+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to make it work in 1 query or do I need at least 2?

Comment: What do you mean with player_id(3 in second row) ?

Comment: @Noob see the SQLFiddle. OP should really put the relevant code and output in the question itself as well, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c36a/23/0)

Same concept as Tim, but with Total_Ranks column

```
SELECT level, cp, R.type, player_id, MinTime, Total_Ranks
FROM runtimes R
JOIN (SELECT TYPE, MIN(LAP_TIME) MinTime, Count(*) Total_Ranks
      FROM RUNTIMES
      GROUP BY TYPE) T on R.Type = T.Type
                      and R.lap_time = T.MinTime
WHERE level=1 
AND cp=1
```

Answer (score 2):

One canonical way to solve this problem in MySQL is to use a subquery to identify the minimum lap time for each type.  Then join your full table to this to obtain the entire record.  Note that a nice side effect of this approach is that we also get back ties if a given type have more than one person sharing the minimum lap time.

```
SELECT r1.*, r2.total_ranks
FROM runtimes r1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT type, MIN(lap_time) AS min_lap_time, COUNT(*) AS total_ranks
    FROM runtimes
    GROUP BY type
) r2
    ON r1.type     = r2.type AND
       r1.lap_time = r2.min_lap_time
```

Here is a link to your updated Fiddle:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Nice one, but you forgot total_ranks.